# Can't render component on State Change (TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react and working on a small project for fetching recipe detail from an external api.
i am able to render the recipe list once the page loads but the challenge i am facing is that i am trying to do a conditional rendering to render the recipe details once a value in the state changes. ie: load the recipe list if PageIndex === 1 and load the recipe details if PageIndex === 0.

The recipe list loads without any problem and i can go to the recipe details page but once i click to go to the recipe details the recipe list components unmounts. when i click on a button to go back to recipe list i then get an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

how do i get the component to rerender when i change value of index back to 1 on button click.

here is my code below

NB: i am passing the props handleIndex to RecipeDetails which is the code i am running when user clicks to go back to recipe List.

App js

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { recipes } from './tempList';
import RecipeList from './components/RecipeList';
import RecipeDetails from './components/RecipeDetails';
import './App.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Header from './components/Header';

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    recipes: [],
    url: 'https://forkify-api.herokuapp.com/api/search?q=pizza',
    details_id: 47746,
    pageIndex: 1,
  });

  const { url, recipes, details_id, pageIndex } = data;

  const getRecipes = () => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((jsonData) => {
        setData({ ...data, recipes: jsonData.recipes });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
  }, []);

  const handleIndex = (index) => {
    setData({ pageIndex: index });
  };

  const handleDetails = (index, id) => {
    setData({
      pageIndex: index,
      details_id: id,
    });
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header />
      {pageIndex === 1 ? (
        <RecipeList recipes={recipes} handleDetails={handleDetails} />
      ) : (
        <RecipeDetails details_id={details_id} handleIndex={handleIndex} />
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Recipe Details

```html
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const RecipeDetails = ({ handleIndex, details_id }) => {
  const [recipeDetails, setRecipeDetails] = useState({
    recipe: [],
  });
  const { recipe } = recipeDetails;

  const id = details_id;
  const url = `https://forkify-api.herokuapp.com/api/get?rId=${id}`;

  const getRecipe = () => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setRecipeDetails({
          recipe: data.recipe,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getRecipe();
  }, []);

  console.log(recipe);

  const {
    image_url,
    title,
    source_url,
    publisher,
    publisher_url,
    ingredients,
  } = recipe;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 my-3'>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Link to='/'>
                <button
                  type='button'
                  className='btn btn-warning mb-5 text-capitalize'
                  onClick={() => handleIndex(1)}
                >
                  back to recipe list
                </button>
              </Link>
            </BrowserRouter>
            <img src={image_url} alt='recipe' className='d-block w-100' />
          </div>
          <div className='col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 my-3'>
            <h6 className='text-uppercase'>{title}</h6>
            <h6 className='text-warning text-capitalize'>
              Publisher: {publisher}
            </h6>
            <a
              href={publisher_url}
              target='_blank'
              rel='noopener noreferrer'
              className='btn btn-primary mt-2 text-capitalize'
            >
              publisher page
            </a>
            <a
              href={source_url}
              target='_blank'
              rel='noopener noreferrer'
              className='btn btn-success mx-3 mt-2 text-capitalize'
            >
              recipe url
            </a>
            <ul className='list-group mt-4'>
              <h2 className='mt-3 mb-4'>Ingredients</h2>
              {ingredients === undefined ? (
                <p>Loading...</p>
              ) : (
                ingredients.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={index} className='list-group-item text-slanted'>
                      {item}
                    </li>
                  );
                })
              )}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default RecipeDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```js
  const handleIndex = (index) => {
    setData(state => ({ ...state, pageIndex: index }));
  };
```

Comment: i tried the function and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update certain line of your code in RecipeDetails.js
Replace

```
const { recipe } = recipeDetails;
```

As

```
const { recipe = {} } = recipeDetails;
```

Then,

Replace

```
const {
image_url, 
title, 
source_url, 
publisher, 
publisher_url, 
ingredients 
} = recipe;
```

As

```
 const {
 image_url = '',
 title = '',
 source_url = '',
 publisher = '',
 publisher_url = '',
 ingredients = [],
 } = recipe;
```

Just give initialisation to your variables otherwise it is going to throw error. This should solve the problem.

Also to add one more thing, in handleIndex function should always previous state as a copy and then update in your state variables.

I have updated the following functions:

```
 const getRecipes = () => {
 fetch(`${url}${string}`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(jsonData => {
    setData({ ...data, recipes: jsonData.recipes });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
  };
```

---

```
const handleIndex = index => {
    setData({ ...data, pageIndex: index });
};
```

---

```
const handleDetails = (index, id) => {
     setData({
         ...data,
         pageIndex: index,
         details_id: id
     });
};
```

---

```
const handleChange = e => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setData({ ...data, search: value });
};
```

---

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   setData({ ...data, url: `${base_url}${search}`, search: '' });
};
```

Comment: thanks for your input. Followed your code but still get the same error. i really cannot tell what i am doing wrong.. can you look into how i am rendering the component. Do you think i am using useEffect the wrong way here?

Comment: Could you please add your RecipeList.js by forking the project and share the url for the same https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6q4njr?file=src%2FApp.js, may be we can solve it then because it works fine when i am just running the RecipeDetails.js component. The problem must be lying when its going to the recipeDetails page once it clicks on one of the item list.

Comment: Hello, here is the link to the forked project. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gfdgx4?file=src/App.js

Comment: Hey i have done corrections in your code , wherever you were setting the data of setData function the properties were not persisiting as it was not making the copy of old object, so updating directly was letting your data to just persit the properties you were trying to update, rest was vanishing up.
Here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ad8hh7?file=src%2FApp.js.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey! i need one last help.. I am trying to catch and return an error when user searches for a recipe and result isn't available but i am running into some error. here is the forked project with my updated code. I would appreciate your help thank you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mhbuur?file=src%2FRecipeList.js

Comment: Hey nevermind, i fixed the code everything working fine now.

Comment: Hello, sorry now i fixed the code i am trying to implement some other stuff. I have ran into a problem trying to render related recipes. Since all recipe details page render when pageIndex === 0. viewing another recipe from the details page seem impossible since in the state pageindex is now === 0. Unless i go back to Recipe list which will change state back to === 1, then i can view any recipe from there. Can you help me with a solution? here is forked project. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mhbuur?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: I see the complexity is adding in your component due to repetated code in Related.js.  You need to little restructure your code. 
Firstly don't use the BrowserRouter inside components make it a wrapper outside where your parent component is . 
Just take the reference from here https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basichttps://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic 
Once it loads default page that will be your pageIndex 1 which you really need not to define then.
After that whenever you want to navigate to pages you can use the hook useHistory().

Comment: With the help of that you can push the page you want to reach. And once you click on the similar items you can pass on the Id and it will rerender your same component (RecipeDetails) then. And no repeated code is required